# Prepopulating Table with Fields in Select List

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

In my python toolbox, I am trying to populate a table with the fields of two different feature classes.

Here the GUI.

[image]

I am trying to list the fields of Baseline Feature Class to the 1st column... 1 field per row.

In the 2nd column, I am trying to populate a dropdown list with the all the field values of the Updated Feature Class.

I've marked up the image below by adding the appearance of a dropdown list in the 2nd column.

The purpose here of the table is to allow the user to associate the fields from the updated feature class to the fields of the baseline feature class since the fields names might differ.

Is it possible to put selection lists in tables and if so, how?

My code so far:

```
class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """lorem etc"""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [SecuredAreas]


class SecuredAreas(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Secured Areas"
        self.description = """lorem etc"""
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """In the getParameterInfo method, tool parameters are defined by
        creating Parameter objects and setting their properties."""

        default_data = {}
        try:
            with open(parameter_values_filename) as data_file:
                default_data = json.load(data_file)
        except:
            pass

        # First parameter
        baseline_name = "sa_baseline_feature_class"
        sa_baseline_feature_class = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="SA Baseline Feature Class",
            name=baseline_name,
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        attr_name = "sa_baseline_feature_class_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            sa_baseline_feature_class.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Second parameter
        new_feature_class_name = "new_feature_class"
        new_feature_class = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Updated Feature Class",
            name=new_feature_class_name,
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        attr_name = "new_feature_class_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            new_feature_class.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Third parameter
        output_workspace = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Set Output Workspace",
            name="output_workspace",
            datatype="DEFolder",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        attr_name = "output_workspace_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            output_workspace.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Fourth parameter
        temporary_workspace = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Temporary Workspace",
            name="temporary_workspace",
            datatype="DEFolder",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        attr_name = "temporary_workspace_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            temporary_workspace.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Fifth parameter
        # "Set up entirely new additions feature class"
        name_for_new_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Name for New Addition Features",
            name="name_for_new_features",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output"
        )
        attr_name = "name_for_new_features_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            name_for_new_features.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Sixth parameter
        name_for_overlap_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Name for Overlap Features",
            name="name_for_overlap_features",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output"
        )
        attr_name = "name_for_overlap_features_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            name_for_overlap_features.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Secenth parameter
        name_for_no_change_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Name for No Change Features",
            name="name_for_no_change_features",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output"
        )
        attr_name = "name_for_no_change_features_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            name_for_no_change_features.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Eigth parameter
        name_for_attr_change_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Name for Attribute Changes Features",
            name="name_for_attr_change_features",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output"
        )
        attr_name = "name_for_attr_change_features_default"
        if attr_name in default_data:
            name_for_attr_change_features.value = default_data[attr_name]

        # Ninth paramter
        search_fields = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Search Fields",
            name="search_fields",
            datatype="Value Table",
            parameterType="Required",
            multiValue=True,
            direction="Input"
        )

        search_fields.parameterDependencies = [sa_baseline_feature_class.name]
        search_fields.columns = [
                ['Field', 'Baseline Field'],
                ['Field', 'Updated Feature Set - Available Fields']
            ]

        params = [sa_baseline_feature_class, new_feature_class,
                  output_workspace, temporary_workspace,
                  name_for_new_features, name_for_overlap_features,
                  name_for_no_change_features, name_for_attr_change_features,
                  search_fields]

        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        sa_baseline_feature_class = parameters[0]
        new_feature_class = parameters[1]
        output_workspace = parameters[2]
        temporary_workspace = parameters[3]
        name_for_new_features = parameters[4]
        name_for_overlap_features = parameters[5]
        name_for_no_change_features = parameters[6]
        name_for_attr_change_features = parameters[7]
        search_fields = parameters[8]

        defaults = {
            'sa_baseline_feature_class_default': sa_baseline_feature_class.valueAsText,
            'new_feature_class_default': new_feature_class.valueAsText,
            'output_workspace_default': output_workspace.valueAsText,
            'temporary_workspace_default': temporary_workspace.valueAsText,
            'name_for_new_features_default': name_for_new_features.valueAsText,
            'name_for_overlap_features_default': name_for_overlap_features.valueAsText,
            'name_for_no_change_features_default': name_for_no_change_features.valueAsText,
            'name_for_attr_change_features_default': name_for_attr_change_features.valueAsText,
        }
        with open(parameter_values_filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(
                    defaults,
                    outfile,
                    indent=4,
                    sort_keys=True,
                    separators=(',', ':')
                    )

        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

        sa_baseline_feature_class = parameters[0].valueAsText
        new_feature_class = parameters[1].valueAsText
        output_workspace = parameters[2].valueAsText
        temporary_workspace = parameters[3].valueAsText
        name_for_new_features = parameters[4].valueAsText
        name_for_overlap_features = parameters[5].valueAsText
        name_for_no_change_features = parameters[6].valueAsText
        name_for_attr_change_features = parameters[7].valueAsText
        search_fields = parameters[8]

        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Comment: Try creating a new tool (for testing) that has only your 2 fields and the table so you're only dealing with what's required in this question, and can simplify the code snippet.

Comment: @Midavalo, yes, should have done that. Thanks for bring it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you want to do is relatively straightforward but there are a few tricky bits. Firstly let me summarise how this process should be formed:

1. Once you load the tool, it initiates itself and calls
   getParameterInfo. Since we do not know yet which feature classes to be
   defined for the first and second parameters, the `Search Fields` should be just defined and empty (I made this `Disabled` for the first instance as well to avoid confusing the user). So the code below is just sufficient (beware a few changes!).

   ```
   # Ninth paramter
   search_fields = arcpy.Parameter(
       displayName = "Search Fields",
       name = "search_fields",
       datatype = 'GPValueTable',
       parameterType = "Required",
       enabled = False,
       direction ="Input"
   )        

   search_fields.parameterDependencies = [sa_baseline_feature_class.name]
   search_fields.columns = [
           ['Field', 'Baseline Field'],
           ['String', 'Updated Feature Set - Available Fields']
       ]
   search_fields.filters[1].type = 'ValueList'
   ```
2. After the user enters two feature classes, we need to populate
   `Search Fields` which should be done via `updateParameters`. However
   there is an issue here, we want to populate the fields of the first
   feature class (updating the values) only once and let user to
   find corresponding fields in the second parameter. Therefore, we
   need a control variable, which I created a class variable, `initiated`.
   This variable should be placed just after class declaration:

   ```
   class SecuredAreas(object):
       initiated = False
   ```
3. After this, the code below should go into `updateParameters`:

   ```
   if parameters[0].altered:
       parameters[8].enabled = True

   if not SecuredAreas.initiated and parameters[1].altered:
       vt = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(parameters[0].value)]
       vt2 = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(parameters[1].value)]
       parameters[8].values = [[a,None] for a in iter(vt)]            
       parameters[8].filters[1].list = vt2
       SecuredAreas.initiated = True
   ```
4. However, there is still an issue, even though we update the values,
   value-list, etc. it will not take effect until another parameter get
   focus, altered and lost focus. This is a persistent issue as
   mentioned in various places as [how to force toolbox to refresh](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/106545),
   for example, without any solution yet.

Comment: Thank you for the comment fatih_dur. There is an issue though. Where you write `search_fields.filters[1].type = 'ValueList'`. When tries to execute, I get an exception: `'Parameter' object has no attribute 'filters' `. Do you know why this might be? Also, what ArcMap version are you using?

Comment: what is your version? This one works in 10.3.1

Comment: I have 10.2.2. Ok, gonna try to download 10.3.1. Thx.